# How to change font style of localised file in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I completely localised my application in Arabic language but now i want to change its "Font Style". I didn't find any help. Xcode change the font style of English language but when i change my iPhone language to Arabic it can't changes the style of Arabic font . How this is possible?

Comment: Do you mean font type?

Comment: yeah like when we talk about "English" then font style is like "TimesNewRoman" or "Arial" etc. Same thing is required for "Arabic".

Comment: Are you using storyboard? If yes, I think storyboard could be viewed in localised(in your case Arabic) language. There you could set the custom font of labels, button etc

Comment: yeah i am using storyboard but i don't think so that it can be viewed in localised manner. I think so, not confirmed. But if we can change it other than English then tell me how. please

Comment: If i have understood correctly, you can detect the phone's current language inside App and set font accordingly.

Comment: Nah man. i am already doing this i.e detecting phone's current language and change the app language. i just want to change the font style of Arabic language. when my phone's language change to Arabic, the Arabic text which is displaying should be in other than the system style. hope you get me.